# Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined in sqlite database

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i new at ionic and i'm trying using plugin cordova sqlite. And i can't read a column.
this is my code, like in all examples, but it is'nt working.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'demo.db', location: 'default' });
            var query = "create table if not exists people (id integer primary key,firstname text,lastname text)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query);
            query = "insert into people values ('a','b')";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query);
            query ="select * from people;";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(result){
                console.log("OVOLIKO :"+result.rows.item.length);
                console.log("Selected: ->" + result.rows.item(0).firstname);
            },function(error){ 
            }); 
        });
```

Error: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined. Can anybody help please.

Comment: `result` is a object or array?

Comment: but on 3-4 tutorials is like this..And the result.rows.item.length is working

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be how you are attempting to access `firstname`. It is attempting to execute an item function with 0 as a parameter(i.e. `item(0)`), as opposed to accessing the first element of the item array(i.e. `item[0]`).

You need to replace `result.rows.item(0).firstname` with `result.rows.item[0].firstname` and I think that will work.